# Switch statements and polymorphism

Tags: c++, switch-statement, polymorphism

I am currently troubled with **dynamic polymorphism**. I have a switch statement that will perform different tasks depending on a condition:

```
switch (condition)
{
   case a:
      foo();
      doSomethingA();
   case b:
      foo();
      doSomethingB();
   case c:
      foo();
      doSomethingC();
}
```

I wanted to create a base object with a virtual method, `doSomething()`, and have this function do `BasePtr->doSomething()`.

I will need to make an appropriate object type depending on this condition, so as far as I know I couldn't avoid that switch.

It would only refactor to:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
switch (condition)
{
   case a:
      base = std::make_unique<DerivedA>();
   case b:
      base = std::make_unique<DerivedB>();
   case c:
      base = std::make_unique<DerivedC>();
}

base->doSomething();
```

This doesn't seem like a complete solution. This switch statement is only used once and the whole logic depending on conditional ends afterwards. This solution won't compress further switch statements into the base switch, which indicates which object to create. What do you think about such a problem?

Comment: If that's the only use of the classes, and "doSomething" will never be called again afterwards, I see no sense in having the classes in the first place. Might as well continue to use the first version of the code.

Comment: Just checking, but I assume the missing `break;` statements were not intentional.

Comment: Maybe make a map and put condition as key and something() as lambda?

Comment: Factory method will work here, with or without polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It is about as compact as you can go. You need a means to configure your base and in your case you used a switch-case.

Consider the example below...

```
Pokemon* pokemon;

switch( mySelection ){
   case 1: pokemon = new Pikachu(); break;
   case 2: pokemon = new Bulbasaur(); break;
   case 3: pokemon = new Charmander(); break;
   default: pokemon = null;
}

if (pokemon!=null)
    pokemon-> specialAttack();
```

Comment: This is not much different from OP's example, except OP's solution is better through the use of smart pointers